# @Autowired create null object inspite @configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have the following configuration class

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class TemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Configuration configuration() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(new Version(2, 3, 23));
        configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(TemplateConfiguration.class, "/templates/");
        configuration.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        configuration.setLocale(Locale.US);
        configuration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

and I use it at the following @service

```
@Service
public class FreeMarkerService {

    @Autowired
    private Configuration configuration;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FreeMarkerService.class);

    public String process() {
        try {
            Template template = configuration.getTemplate("someName");
            ....
        } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
            logger.error("Error while processing FreeMarker template: " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to call process() like

```
FreeMarkerService f = new FreeMarkerService()
f.process()
```

I get a null exception cause the configuration Object is null

I want to create an instance using @Autowired and @Configuration annotations 
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the Spring instantiated `FreeMarkerService` object avoiding use of `new` keyword for objects like Controllers or Services as possible.

For example,

```
@Service
public class SampleService {

    @Autowired
    private FreeMarkerService freeMarkerService;

    public String callProcess() {
        return freeMarkerService.process();
    }
}
```

More details you can find in many posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null).

Answer (score 2):

This is a member injection:

```
@Autowired
private static Configuration configuration;
```

Which spring does after instantiating the bean from its constructor. So at the time you are making that static method call spring has not injected the value.

Comment: so, what should I do? cause even after removing the static modifier , spring doesn't create the Configuration class , and configuration is still null

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to autowire a static field. This is not possible in Spring. Remove static from your Configuration property and it should work.

```
@Autowired
private Configuration configuration;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Autowired
 private static Configuration configuration;
```

Why autowired a static field? this is the reason. static member load as class definition load so it is not getting injected value and getting default value which is null.

Comment: removed static, still null

Comment: check your configuration class is getting injected correctly, and stop using new for instantiating.